# Jquery Background Position reversed when used with jquery css selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding the background-position by using jquery. It works but the problem is even though data is like `"center top"` but while adding the `"top center"`

**HTML**

---

```
<section class="ggowl-background-wrapper" 
          data-ggowl="{&quot;backgroundimage&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/dev.geekygreenowl.online\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/08\/aperture-science-wallpaper.jpg&quot;,&quot;backgroundimagehover&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/dev.geekygreenowl.online\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/08\/aperture-science-wallpaper.jpg&quot;,&quot;backgroundposition&quot;:&quot;bottom right&quot;}" 
          data-id="5df0d84" data-element_type="section" 
          data-settings="{&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}" 
          style="background-image: url(&quot;http://dev.geekygreenowl.online/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/aperture-science-wallpaper.jpg&quot;); background-position: right bottom;">
    <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
        <div class="elementor-row">
            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-4aede67 elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column" data-id="4aede67" data-element_type="column">
                <div class="elementor-column-wrap">
                    <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

---

**Javascript**

---

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  sm = parseInt(ggowlDataLoder.sm); //460 - loaded from database
  md = parseInt(ggowlDataLoder.md); //720 - loaded from database
  lg = parseInt(ggowlDataLoder.lg); //1120 - loaded from database

  var ggowlIsBreakPoint = function (bp) {
      var bps = [sm, md, lg],
          w = $(window).width(),
          min, max
      for (var i = 0, l = bps.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (bps[i] === bp) {
          min = bps[i-1] || 0
          max = bps[i]
          break
        }
      }
      return w > min && w <= max
  }

  function ggowlAdjustSize(){
  $('.ggowl-background-wrapper').each(function(){
        var ggowlData = jQuery.parseJSON( $(this).attr('data-ggowl'));
        console.log(ggowlData.backgroundposition_sm); //returns correctly
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + ggowlData.backgroundimage + ')'); // working fine - Tested

        if(ggowlIsBreakPoint(sm)){
            $(this).css('background-position', ggowlData.backgroundposition_sm); //get's reveresed
        }else if(ggowlIsBreakPoint(md)){
            $(this).css('background-position', ggowlData.backgroundposition_md); //get's reveresed
        }else {
           $(this).css('background-position', ggowlData.backgroundposition_lg); //get's reveresed
        }
    });
  }
  $(window).on('resize', ggowlAdjustSize);
  ggowlAdjustSize();

});
```

Don't know why it is reversing the position . if i do `console.log(ggowlData.backgroundposition_sm);` outside the jquery css attribute it shows correctly but `$(this).css('background-position', ggowlData.backgroundposition_sm);` this makes it reveresed

Pls help

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is reversing the words. `left center` becomes `center left` .I did it in server-side. So when passed to CSS it shows correctly. `background-position-x` is not recommended to use.